# How to get column values from list which contains column names in spark scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a config defined which contains a list of column for each table to be used as a dedup key

for ex:
config 1 :

```
val lst = List(section_xid, learner_xid)
```

these are the column that needs to be used as a dedup keys. This list is dynamic some table will have 1 value some will have 2 or 3 values in it

what I am trying to do is build a single key column from this list

```
df.
.withColumn( "dedup_key_sk", uuid(md5(concat($"lst(0)",$"lst(1)"))) )
```

how do I make this dynamic which will work for any number of columns in list .
I tried doing this

```
df.withColumn("dedup_key_sk", concat(Seq($"col1", $"col2"):_*))
```

For this to work I had to convert list to Df and each value in list needs to be in separate columns I was not able to figure that out.

tried doing this but didn't work

```
val res = sc.parallelize(List((lst))).toDF
```

ANy input here will be appreciated . Thank you

Comment: is `lst` a list of strings?

Comment: Yes It is a list of strings always @werner

Answer (score 0):

The list of strings can be [mapped](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):List%5BB%5D) to a list of columns (using [functions.col](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#col(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)). This list of columns can then be used with `concat`:

```scala
val lst: List[String] = List("section_xid", "learner_xid")
df.withColumn("dedup_key_sk", concat(lst.map(col):_*)).show()
```